# setup rbl server

Tags: linux, email

How can i setup my own RBL (real time blacklist)server.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a project I've found: http://www.blue-quartz.com/rbl/

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Use one of the tens of existing RBLs that are properly maintained and managed.